# How to generating Excel File with multi sheet by using SQL Server 2012?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012, c#-5.0

I need to create a stored procedure or query in SQL Server 2012 to take a data table from C# code, and create an Excel file with multiple sheets based on the data that exists in said data table.

From data below as an example, I have a function `GetDate` returning data table.

Create File ABC.xlsx with two sheets - first sheet name source and second sheet name types, and load data related to every sheet based on data.

So the result will be a new file `Abc.xlsx` with two sheets `Source` and `Types` and every sheet has one row of data.

```
public static DataTable GetData() 
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("PartId", typeof(int));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Files", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Tab", typeof(string));

    dataTable.Rows.Add(1222,"micro","Abc","source");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(1321, "silicon", "Abc", "Types");

    return dataTable;
}
```

Can SQL Server 2012 create Excel files with multiple sheets or not?

I can do that in C# but from SQL I cannot; so how can I achieve that from SQL Server 2012 by any way ?

Comment: SQL Server is **definitely NOT** the system to use to create Excel sheets ! If you already have the data in your C# code - use any of the many Excel libraries in C# to create the Excel file right there! Much easier....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL stored procedure it's not necessary for this. You can create the .xlsx file directly from C# iterating over the data rows. Something like:

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
var data = GetData();
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
     var worksheet = xlApp.Worksheets.Add();
     worksheet.Name = row["Tab"].ToString();
}

xlWorkbook.SaveAs("path.xlsx");
```

Some more detailed docs about Microsoft.Office.Interop [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)

Personally, I would go to a NuGet package for the .xlsx file creation since with Microsoft.Office.Interop you need the Excel from Office actually installed on the machine you're running the code (maybe that won't be installed on you deployment server and may cost more money to install it).

My personal preference for this is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PicoXLSX/) NuGet package.

Good luck!